# How serializers and reponse data pls Django-rest

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I am doing a small project in Django with the rest framework and I reached a point where I don't really know how to continue.
In the application, my order model like this

```
class Order(models.Model):
    drink = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    total = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    ordered_at = models.DateField(default=timezone.now)
```

i want custom reponse like this . I think will use distinct(), and group_by but i don't how do it apply to serializer . If i use views.APIViews i think i can do it . But i want use serializer and use pagination of django for that api .

```
[
    {   
        "id": 1,
        "ordered_at": "2020-09-19",
        "orders": [
          {
              "id": 64,
              "drink": "",
              "total": 200000,
              "ordered_at": "2020-09-19"
          },
          {
              "id": 65,
              "drink": "",
              "total": 200000,
              "ordered_at": "2020-09-19"
          }
    ]
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "ordered_at": "2020-09-18",
        "orders": [
          {
              "id": 63,
              "drink": "",
              "total": 200000,
              "ordered_at": "2020-09-18"
          }
          ]
    }
]
```

Comment: read django documentations